# Mixed Content Warning in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, .net, https

Hey there stack overflow enthusiasts.

I am getting this mixed content warning in Internet Explorer.
[image: This is the Warning I get]

It is annoying some of my end users.  I know that there is a couple of solutions to this problem by browsing stack overflow (one browser based and one code based).  I have looked at what might be being requested via http as apposed to https (using Fidler and chromes dev tools) and everything is being requested via http.

However, I did notice something strange.  Looking at http I found out that the browser is looking for a specific .gif file and it can't seem to find it.  Upon further investigation, it looks like it was part of a jquery package I downloaded (timeentry.js).  The Jquery file is found and it is working.  But that gif file just doesn't look like it is showing up.  I am going to ask another SO question about how to get that timeentry jquery file to work with that gif file.  But my question for  you is, will you still run into a mixed content warning if everyything is attempted to be loaded via https but the browser can't still find certain content?

Have you every run into a similar issue and resolved it?  Any help with this would be great!

Comment: Nope, That dialog *only* shows up when you're requesting content from bith http and https within the same page. Never seen it for missing content myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes: the message is raised by the browser (at least IE) prior to retrieving the data in order to protect the user.

The reasoning behind this is that it wouldn't do much good to access the content, then tell the user there might be a problem.

Comment: Firefox (3 or 4 at least, I'm not sure if this has changed recently) was making the request anyway unfortunately (only whether to display the resulting page was the object of the yes/no dialog box).

Comment: I just figured out how to load the offending file.  And It still doesn't work?